# Angular Universal: lifecycle hook for when window api becomes available

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I have implemented server-side rendering with Angular Universal. I have a method that I want to fire when the DOM is interactive and browser apis like `window.navigator` become available (because I want to do something with the user's locale).

Is there a lifecycle hook or some other way to listen for when I can use `window.navigator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested running my node server locally and found that `ngOnInit()` is a suitable place to run navigator code. `ngOnInit()` will get called server side but will get called again in the browser, so you need truthy checks on navigator:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.window && this.window.navigator) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

It's worth noting I'm using a [window provider](https://brianflove.com/2018/01/11/angular-window-provider/) to access window -

```
constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window: any) { }
```